# Regex to validate week and year

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a string with this pattern: ww/yyyy.

With: `^([0-9]{4})`, I check if the year has 4 digits.

I tried to put these two regex together without success.

```
(5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|0[1-9])/^([0-9]{4})
```

Answer (score 3):

`^` means the start of a line or the start of the string (depends on options on the regex implementation.) So try this:

```
^(5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|0[1-9])/([0-9]{4})$
```

`$` means the end of the line or end of the string.

If you don't include `^` and `$` in the pattern, something like this will get matched: `foo20/2000bar`.

Comment: You very likely need to escape the slash with a backslash: `\/`.

Answer (score 2):

How about other way, though both mean same:

```
^((0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0123])/([0-9]{4}))$
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

`(5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|0[1-9])/([0-9]{4})` why did you need the `^` character?